# Android: Gaining access to other app files through app on non rooted phone

Tags: android, backup, root

Does anyone know if it is possible to access the data files from another app on your app? Really just copying a directory plus contents. This is for a backup system. I am trying to create a backup system that works decently on non rooted phones. I currently can only copy data from my own app. I can't navigate further up the file system. Getting a permission denied.

Answer (score 1):

No. AFAIK, Not possible on non-rooted phones. Android restricts access to only your app specific content.